# Blogger Custom Template HTML Breaks Layout Page

Tags: blogger

I am trying to make a Blogger template from scratch and have been looking at the code from the generated ones. I don't care about having it fully editable and having the layout able to be changed from the admin panel but I don't want it to be completely broken.[image]

The header is all messed up as you can see and is under the Favicon box. In actual practice, the template is working just fine but in this window it clearly isn't. The following is an outline of what I have come up with.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <b:skin>
        <![CDATA[
            body {
                background: white;
                color: black;
            }
        ]]>
        </b:skin>
        <b:include data="blog" name="all-head-content" />
        <title><data:blog.pageTitle /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b:section id="navbar" maxwidgets="1" showaddelement="no">
            <b:widget id="Navbar1" locked="true" title="Navbar" type="Navbar"></b:widget>
        </b:section>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <b:section id="header" maxwidgets="1" showaddelement="no">
                <b:widget id="Header1" locked="true" title="Header" type="Header"></b:widget>
            </b:section>
            <b:section id="menu">
                <b:widget id="PageList1" locked="true" title="Pages" type="PageList"></b:widget>
            </b:section>
            <b:section id="main">
                <b:widget id="Blog1" locked="true" title="Blog Posts" type="Blog"></b:widget>
            </b:section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am fairly sure you could copy and paste the above as the template HTML and get the same problem!

- Is it because my layout isn't the same? I see a bunch of (if not all) the templates that I was using as an example use class names and id like `fauxcolumn-outer` and `body-fauxcolumn-outer`.
- Follow up question: when I enable or disable or drag around different parts of a page like where the location is displayed in the post header... how does that work? My template clearly doesn't support that because I never told it to so are there guidelines to that or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I don't know why this always happens but I find out what went wrong just after asking a question. So I started trying a bunch of stuff and I remember seeing a few tags that looked like ` lying around. So I tried that and it fixed part of it. So I remember a page about the navbar that I saw before so I went to find it again and on it, it says:

[About the Navar](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/42269?hl=en)

> **Notes:**
>
> We've made every effort to make sure the Navbar doesn't interfere with custom template designs. However, some display problems may occur. Here are a few things to try if you are running into trouble:
>
> - add style="margin-top:40px;" to the topmost element of your Template. (i.e.  would become )
> - make sure the closing  tag is present; it should go before the  tag.

So in short... from my question the fixed template code is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <b:skin>
        <![CDATA[
            body {
                background: white;
                color: black;
            }
        ]]>
        </b:skin>
        <b:include data="blog" name="all-head-content" />
        <title><data:blog.pageTitle /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b:section id="navbar" maxwidgets="1" showaddelement="no">
            <b:widget id="Navbar1" locked="true" title="Navbar" type="Navbar"></b:widget>
        </b:section>
        <div id="wrapper" style="clear:both; margin-top: 50px;">
            <b:section id="header" maxwidgets="1" showaddelement="no">
                <b:widget id="Header1" locked="true" title="Header" type="Header"></b:widget>
            </b:section>
            <b:section id="menu">
                <b:widget id="PageList1" locked="true" title="Pages" type="PageList"></b:widget>
            </b:section>
            <b:section id="main">
                <b:widget id="Blog1" locked="true" title="Blog Posts" type="Blog"></b:widget>
            </b:section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**notice the style on the `#wrapper`**

Comment: Why would you want your template to look correct in the backend? As long as it works fine, I really wouldn't bother too much about it.
Also if you are trying to create a responsive template, I would recommend writing your template based on five (a german blogger created it, it has all the elements you need but with a much nicer markup, like really). It is much easier then. If you're interested, I did write a few tutorials. about it. http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/2014/09/write-responsive-blogger-template-fast.html if you wanna check it out